# VBA to find specific word and copy value to another cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I am looking for help with vba.

I want to search column A for "Summary of CAMBUSLANG" and if found assign the value that is in column D to another cell for talking sake say Column A of another spreadsheet.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far, and what is your specific problem? See [ask] then [edit] your question to include your code, and any appropriate errors.

Comment: Why not just use a Vlookup function here?

Comment: I have another spreadsheet that has 13 reporting periods, I have set up a recorded macros and a button for each reporting period.  When the reporting period ends you click the button and it goes to various spreadsheets etc picking up values (basically saving manual input).  The issue I have is one spreadsheet in particular has a list of codes with an amount, at the bottom the amount is a total (figure I want), for some reporting periods a code could be removed and instead of my recorded macro picking up the total value from D33 it picks it from D32 therefore inserting the incorrect figure.

Comment: Also I have scoured the internet using a search engine and thought I would try here for help as I could not find anything that could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Range.Find Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) to find your specific string in column A and the [Range.Offset Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset) to move to column D:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim FoundAt As Range
    Set FoundAt = Worksheets("SearchSheet").Columns("A").Find(What:="Summary of CAMBUSLANG", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not FoundAt Is Nothing Then 
        Worksheets("AnotherSheet").Range("A1").Value = FoundAt.Offset(ColumnOffset:=3).Value
    Else 'nothing found
        MsgBox "'Summary of CAMBUSLANG' not found.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```